# A remote access exception in DolphinDB,Can't find the object with name loadTable('dfs://zctestDB','trainInfoTable')

Tags: sql, database, distributed-system, dolphindb

I want to remotely query the database in DolphinDB.The database is created on the server 38.124.2.173 with the following script in the server ,

```
tableSchema = table(100:0,`trainID`ts`tag01`tag02,`tag03,[INT,TIMESTAMP,FLOAT,FLOAT,FLOAT )

db1 = database("",VALUE,(today()-92)..(today()+60))
db2 = database("",RANGE,0..80*10+1)
db = database("dfs://zctestDB",COMPO,[db1,db2])
dfsTable = db.createPartitionedTable(tableSchema,"trainInfoTable",`ts`trainID)
```

My query code as below,

```
def testParallelQuery( connVector,trainIDs,startTime, endTime ){
cols=`trainID`ts`tag01
whereConditions=[<trainID in trainIDs>,expr(sqlCol(`ts),between,startTime:endTime)]
script=sql(sqlCol(cols),"loadTable('dfs://zctestDB','trainInfoTable')",whereConditions)
return ploop(remoteRun{,script}, connVector)
}
host="38.124.2.173"
port=30599
connVector = loop(xdb, take(host, 10), port, "admin", "123456")
testParallelQuery( connVector,1..5,2019.06.14T00:00:00.000, 2019.06.14T01:00:00.000 )
```

The following exception occurred after I ran it，

```
Error was raised when execution : Can't find the object with name loadTable('dfs://zctestDB','trainInfoTable')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Function `sql` helps one construct a sql statement dynamically. The parameter `from` accepts three types of data: (1) a table object, (2) an expression representing a table or a table join, (3) a variable associated with a table object.

In your particular case, please pass an expression to `from` as follows.

```
def runSQL(trainIDs, startTime, endTime){
    cols = `trainID`ts`tag01
    whereConditions = [<trainID in trainIDs>, expr(sqlCol(`ts), between, startTime:endTime)]
    return sql(sqlCol(cols), loadTable('dfs://zctestDB','trainInfoTable'), whereConditions).eval()
}

def testParallelQuery( connVector,trainIDs,startTime, endTime ){
    return ploop(remoteRun{,runSQL{trainIDs, startTime, endTime}}, connVector)
}

host="38.124.2.173"
port=30599
connVector = loop(xdb, take(host, 10), port, "admin", "123456")
testParallelQuery( connVector,1..5,2019.06.14T00:00:00.000, 2019.06.14T01:00:00.000 )
```